# sfWidgetFormChoice rendered as an unordered list

Tags: forms, symfony1

I'm using symfony 1.4.3

Is there some way to render a sfWidgetFormChoice as an unordered list?

In the API there is an option called 'renderer_class' but I can't find any documentation or example about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are always free to browse existing formatter classes

Comment: Yes, but thing is I don't know how to use them... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take a look at `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormSelect.class.php` for example. Basically, what you need to do is implement a class that extends `sfWidgetFormChoiceBase` and write a method `render()` therein. A minimal example would look like this:

```
<?php
class sfWidgetFormChoiceUnordered extends sfWidgetFormChoiceBase
{
    public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
    {
        $result = '<ul>'
        $choices = $this->getChoices();
        foreach ($choices as $choice) {
            $result .= '<li>' . $choice . '</li>';
        }
        return $result .= '</ul>';
    }
}
```

You can put this in `/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormChoiceUnordered.class.php`. Then you need to set the `renderer_class` option on the `sfWidgetFormChoice` widget like you already found out. Set it to the name of the class we just wrote: `sfWidgetFormChoiceUnordered`.

Example:

```
...
$this->addWidget('choice', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'renderer_class' => 'sfWidgetFormChoiceUnordered'
));
...
```

For documentation on the arguments to `render()`, check out the example class I posted above.