# Pass different class name

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I do have the following form:

```
 'region' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true,'choices' => $region))
```

I get the folloing html.

```
 <ul class="radio_list">
   <li> first...
   <li> second....
```

I want to change the name of class in the table. It shouldn't be `radio_list`. I want to name it by my own?
How can I do it in  'region'?

Following is not working and changes the classes of `<li>`:

```
'region' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true,'choices' => $region), array('class' => 'your_class'))
```

Thanks!

Gunnar

This is my complete Widget:

```
        $this->setWidgets(array(
        'recipename' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size' => '40', 'maxlength' => '150')),
        'description' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size' => '40', 'maxlength' => '100')),
        'ingredients' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('rows' => '10', 'cols' => '35')),
        'preparation' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('rows' => '10', 'cols' => '35')),
        'kis' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true, 'choices' => $kis)),
        'category' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true, 'choices' => $category)),
        'region' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('expanded' => true, 'choices' => $region)),
    ));
```

Comment: There is a similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517328/sfwidgetformchoice-rendered-as-an-unordered-list) that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `renderer_options` for that, since `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` overrides passed attribute with it's own option.

```
new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => $region,
    'renderer_options' => array(
        'class' => 'your_class'
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I didn't get the syntax of symfony because I have tried it somehow this way and it didn't work. But your way is working!!! Thanks! (Danke!)